# parse server curl request example

Tags: ios, node.js, mobile, parse-server

After parse.com announced that they are going to close Parse support, i've started to migrate the db and parse server to my vps.

Everything was fine with the migration and with the server. They are up and running

Now with the request example

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: myAppId" \
  -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: myMasterKey" \
  -G \
  http://<myIp>:1337/parse/classes/Defaults/
```

got an error **`{"code":101,"error":"Object not found."}`**

I check the Defaults db is there with its data.

Is there any chance to make the request in a proper curl example or from the browser?

thanks

Comment: Is that really the full request? I just tried it (I was suspecting the trailing slash to be issue) and it worked fine for me. This error would refer to an object being requested by its ID but it does not exist. Also check that you have the latest version of the server installed

Comment: did you try url path that include "/1/"   ie /parse/1/classes/...

Comment: @RobertRowntree i am not using RESTAPi , trying to run my own server, but thanks

Comment: chek out appengine migration https://medium.com/google-cloud/deploying-parse-server-to-google-app-engine-6bc0b7451d50

Comment: Have you set the correct database Uri in the ParseServer variable in index.js  e.g.: var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',

Comment: i did it with node.js with request npm, worked great